# Connect VM to VPN

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to connect my Linux virtual machine(VM) to my corporate VPN via Google Compute Engine. I can make this work on my own Ubuntu computer following this tutorial:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient#PPTP

I do the same steps on my cloud compute engine VM but when I run it, it gives me the error in SSH:

> mats@instance-1:~$ sudo pon eurvpn nodetach
>
> Using interface ppp0
>
> Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2
>
> Modem hangup
>
> Connection terminated.

May it have something to do with the firewall settings? On the website of my company it says:

> Client ports: 1024-65535/TCP
>
> Server port: 1723/TCP
>
> Protocol: PPTP
>
> Allow: IP PROTOCOL 47 (GRE)

And of course I have the gateway, my username and password.
What should I change to my Firewall settings or is there another issue? Help is greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,

Mats

Comment: Try opening ports 1723 and 47 (TCP) and give it another go. Also read [this](http://windowsitpro.com/networking/which-ports-do-you-need-open-firewall-allow-pptp-and-l2tp-over-ipsec-vpn-tunnels)

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this issue? If so please consider posting a self-answer so the community can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

It might has something to do with port forwading, give [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/) a try.